# Android получение картинок из Api (Json)

Tags: android, retrofit, picasso

Здравствуйте, у меня стоит задача в том что я из api получил данные, положил это в список(автомастерские), список я сделал, но не пойму как подгружать фото этих мастерских, знаю что это делается с помощью picasso, но с ним не работал, и вот пытаюсь понять как это делать, буду очень благодарен за помощь.
Api: http://gdetut.com/api/firms?salt=63926e380bdc96ef990d57898daeb71c&category_id=1
Viewer: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

p.s. Что int image надо сделать String csv_image знаю, не успел переделать.

Retrofit class:

```
public class Retrofit {

private static final String ENDPOINT = "http://gdetut.com/api";
private static ApiInterface apiInterface;

interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("/firms?salt=63926e380bdc96ef990d57898daeb71c&category_id=1")
    void getPlaces(Callback<List<Places>> callback);


} 

static {
    init();
}

private static void init() {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();
    apiInterface = restAdapter.create(ApiInterface.class);
}

public static void getPlaces (Callback<List<Places>> callback) {
    apiInterface.getPlaces(callback);
 }

}
```

Retrofit success in Activity:

```
Retrofit.getPlaces(new Callback<List<Places>>() {
    @Override
    public void success(List<Places> places, Response response) {


        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, places));
```

Adapter:

```
  class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Places> {

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Places> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, objects);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.nameOfPlace = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name_id);
        holder.subcategory_name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subcategory_name_id);
        holder.geometryName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.geometry_name_id);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image_id);
        holder.rating = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rating_id);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    Places places = getItem(position);
    holder.nameOfPlace.setText(places.getName());
    holder.subcategory_name.setText(places.getSubcategory_name());
    holder.geometryName.setText(places.getGeometry_name());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(places.getImage());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.restaurant48);
    holder.rating.setText(places.getRating());


    return rowView;
}

class ViewHolder {

    public TextView nameOfPlace;
    public TextView subcategory_name;
    public TextView geometryName;
    public TextView rating;
    public ImageView imageView;
 }
}
```

Places class:

```
    public class Places implements Serializable {


String name;
String geometry_name;
String rating;
String subcategory_name;
int image;

public Places(String name, String geometry_name, String rating,String, subcategory_name, int image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.geometry_name = geometry_name;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.subcategory_name = subcategory_name;
    this.image = image;
}



public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getGeometry_name() {
    return geometry_name;
}

public void setGeometry_name(String geometry_name) {
    this.geometry_name = geometry_name;
}

public String getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(String rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

public String getSubcategory_name() {
    return subcategory_name;
}

public void setSubcategory_name(String subcategory_name) {
    this.subcategory_name = subcategory_name;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала подключаем Picasso в gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

В ответ на запрос приходит прямая ссылка на изображение,поэтому всё просто:

```
Picasso.with(convertView.getContext()).load(places.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
```

При желании можешь подставить placeholder на время загрузки картинки и error на случай ошибки:

```
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.error)
```